# Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames

Tags: r, csv, file, lapply

Suppose we have files *file1.csv*, *file2.csv*, ... , and *file100.csv* in directory *C:\R\Data* and we want to read them all into separate data frames (e.g. *file1*, *file2*, ... , and *file100*).

The reason for this is that, despite having similar names they have different file structures, so it is not that useful to have them in a list.

I could use `lapply` but that returns a single list containing 100 data frames.  Instead I want these data frames in the Global Environment.

How do I read multiple files directly into the global environment? Or, alternatively, How do I unpack the contents of a list of data frames into it?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Please see comment to @hadley below.  Note I did not ask "What is the best way to read X number of files into R?".  My question is more specific for a reason.  I guess I should not have said I wanted to read 100 files (simply trying to be general) but 8 different files with similar names.  But there are too many people here off on their high horse.

Comment: For people who happen upon this post and have a set of 100 identically (or nearly so) structured files, your best bet is to read the data into a named list as hadley and joran explain below. For an additional perspective, take a look at Gregor's response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) as to why this is beneficial.

Comment: If they are completely different structures, how is reading them in a loop helpful? They need to be handled by separate code anyway! — Just read them separately.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Quick draft, untested:

1. Use `list.files()` aka `dir()` to dynamically generate your list of files.
2. This returns a vector, just run along the vector in a `for` loop.
3. Read the i-th file, then use `assign()` to place the content into a new variable file_i

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Thanks, that works.  Indeed that is what I tried to do originally but using `i <- read.csv(...)` inside the loop instead of `assign(i,read.csv(...))`.  Why doesn't the former work?

Comment: Local scope versus global environment. You could try `i <<- read.csv(...)` as well.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Many thanks, final question: Had I used `lapply` and dumped everything inside a list, how would I "unpack it"?  I ask because `lapply` is much faster and I dislike loops.

Comment: Prove that `lapply` is faster in reading N files.  Moreover, if *you* dislike loops the burden is on you to read up on the `*apply` family.  And again, these days they are *not* generally faster.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Thanks. I was always told to avoid loops in `R`.  Vectorization and all that. But maybe is all lore...  Easy to find out with `system.time()` I suppose.

Comment: Precisely. Profiling beats old wife's tales.

Comment: Yowser, assign and <<- in the same answer! Has someone hijacked Dirk's account?

Answer (score 38):

Thank you all for replying.

For completeness here is my final answer for loading any number of (tab) delimited files, in this case with 6 columns of data each where column 1 is characters, 2 is factor, and remainder numeric:

```
##Read files named xyz1111.csv, xyz2222.csv, etc.
filenames <- list.files(path="../Data/original_data",
    pattern="xyz+.*csv")

##Create list of data frame names without the ".csv" part 
names <-substr(filenames,1,7)

###Load all files
for(i in names){
    filepath <- file.path("../Data/original_data/",paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
    assign(i, read.delim(filepath,
    colClasses=c("character","factor",rep("numeric",4)),
    sep = "\t"))
}
```

Comment: for(i in 1:length(names)

Answer (score 17):

Use `assign` with a character variable containing the desired name of your data frame.

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
   oname = paste("file", i, sep="")
   assign(oname, read.csv(paste(oname, ".txt", sep="")))
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This answer is intended as a more useful complement to Hadley's answer.

While the OP specifically wanted each file read into their R workspace as a separate object, many *other* people naively landing on this question may *think* that that's what they want to do, when in fact they'd be better off reading the files into a single list of data frames.

So for the record, here's how you might do that.

```
#If the path is different than your working directory
# you'll need to set full.names = TRUE to get the full
# paths.
my_files <- list.files("path/to/files")

#Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
all_csv <- lapply(my_files,read.csv,...)

#Set the name of each list element to its
# respective file name. Note full.names = FALSE to
# get only the file names, not the full path.
names(all_csv) <- gsub(".csv","",
                       list.files("path/to/files",full.names = FALSE),
                       fixed = TRUE)
```

Now any of the files can be referred to by `my_files[["filename"]]`, which really isn't much *worse* that just having separate `filename` variables in your workspace, and often it is much more convenient.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to unpack a list of data.frames using just lapply

```
filenames <- list.files(path="../Data/original_data",
                        pattern="xyz+.*csv")

filelist <- lappy(filenames, read.csv)

#if necessary, assign names to data.frames
names(filelist) <- c("one","two","three")

#note the invisible function keeps lapply from spitting out the data.frames to the console

invisible(lapply(names(filelist), function(x) assign(x,filelist[[x]],envir=.GlobalEnv)))
```

Comment: You can "automate" the naming with `paste0("sheet_",1:length(filelist))`.

Comment: When I use this method, the space between my column names is replaced by a ".". For example column "Warehouse Code" becomes "Warehouse.Code". Do you know how to keep the column format unchanged?

Comment: Hi! I'm wondering, how i can pass to `read.csv` function a number of parameters instead of calling it with the default ones? E.g. `read.csv(as.is = T, header = T, comment.char = "")` .

Answer (score 6):

Reading all the CSV files from a folder and creating vactors same as the file names:

```
setwd("your path to folder where CSVs are")

filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))

for(i in filenames){
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to access the elements of a list from the global environment is to `attach` the list.  Note that this actually creates a new environment on the search path and copies the elements of your list into it, so you may want to remove the original list after attaching to prevent having two potentially different copies floating around.

Comment: I'm upvoting, but example code would be even better.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Example code would be `attach(mylist)`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I was trying to connect your answer to the original question, how it relates to ``list.files`` to ``assign`` and other things mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I want to update the answer given by Joran:

```
#If the path is different than your working directory
# you'll need to set full.names = TRUE to get the full
# paths.
my_files <- list.files(path="set your directory here", full.names=TRUE)
#full.names=TRUE is important to be added here

#Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
all_csv <- lapply(my_files, read.csv)

#Set the name of each list element to its
# respective file name. Note full.names = FALSE to
# get only the file names, not the full path.
names(all_csv) <- gsub(".csv","",list.files("copy and paste your directory here",full.names = FALSE),fixed = TRUE)

#Now you can create a dataset based on each filename
df <- as.data.frame(all_csv$nameofyourfilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

a simplified version, assuming your csv files are in the working directory:

```
listcsv <- list.files(pattern= "*.csv") #creates list from csv files
names <- substr(listcsv,1,nchar(listcsv)-4) #creates list of file names, no .csv
for (k in 1:length(listcsv)){
  assign(names[[k]] , read.csv(listcsv[k]))
}
#cycles through the names and assigns each relevant dataframe using read.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#copy all the files you want to read in R in your working directory
a <- dir()
#using lapply to remove the".csv" from the filename 
for(i in a){
list1 <- lapply(a, function(x) gsub(".csv","",x))
}
#Final step 
for(i in list1){
filepath <- file.path("../Data/original_data/..",paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
assign(i, read.csv(filepath))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `list.files` and  `map_dfr` to read many csv files

```
df <- list.files(data_folder, full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(read_csv)
```

## Reproducible example

First write sample csv files to a temporary directory.
It's more complicated than I thought it would be.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(purrrlyr)
library(readr)
data_folder <- file.path(tempdir(), "iris")
dir.create(data_folder)
iris %>%
    # Keep the Species column in the output
    # Create a new column that will be used as the grouping variable
    mutate(species_group = Species) %>%
    group_by(species_group) %>%
    nest() %>%
    by_row(~write.csv(.$data,
                      file = file.path(data_folder, paste0(.$species_group, ".csv")),
                      row.names = FALSE))
```

Read these csv files into one data frame.
Note the Species column has to be present in the csv files, otherwise we would loose that information.

```
iris_csv <- list.files(data_folder, full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(read_csv)
```

Comment: The question asked how to read all the files as separate data frames, not one dataframe.

Comment: @jas thank you. It is correct. I moved this answer to a new question and answer called [How to read multiple csv files into a single data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222347/how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-into-a-single-data-frame-in-r/75222348#75222348)