# reading csv files in a for loop and assigning dataframe names

Tags: r, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

I need to read many csv files into dataframes from one folder. The csv file names are of the form ***fxpair-yyyy-mm.csv*** (e.g. AUDJPY-2009-05.csv). I want to read all csv files in and create dataframes of the form ***fxpair.yyyy.mm***

I am having trouble creating the dataframe names in the loop for assignment from the read.csv statements

```
filenames <- list.files(path=getwd())  
numfiles <- length(filenames)  

#fx.data.frames to hold names that will be assigned to csv files in csv.read
fx.data.frames <- gsub(pattern="-",x=filenames,replacement=".")  
fx.data.frames <- gsub(pattern=".csv",x=fx.data.frames,replacement="")

i <-1  
for (i in c(1:numfiles)){  
   filenames[i] <- paste(".\\",filenames[i],sep="")  
   fx.data.frames[i] <- read.csv(filenames[i], header=FALSE)
}
```

The csv.read seems to work fine but I am not able to create the dataframe objects in the way I intend. I just want some way to name the dataframes read in the ***fxpair.yyyy.mm*** format based on the file name.

Am I missing something obvius? THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!!

Comment: also see another stackoverflow question involving reading multiple text files into R http://goo.gl/jM1J7. Keep in mind that it is easier to deal with a list of data frames in R, rather than writing each file to a different data frame, as processing becomes easier.

Comment: On a sidenote : in R you don't have to initialize i, and you can just use `for (i in 1:numfiles)` and drop the `c`. Even better, just use `for (i in filenames)` in your loop, saves you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 7):

Just to illustrate my comment :

```
for (i in filenames){  
   name <- gsub("-",".",i)
   name <- gsub(".csv","",name)  
   i <- paste(".\\",i,sep="")
   assign(name,read.csv(i, header=FALSE)
}
```

Or, to save all dataframes in a list :

```
All <- lapply(filenames,function(i){
    i <- paste(".\\",i,sep="")
    read.csv(i, header=FALSE)
})
filenames <- gsub("-",".",filenames)
names(All) <- gsub(".csv","",filenames)
```

I'd go for the second solution, as I like working with lists. It's less of a hassle to clean up the workspace afterwards. You also get rid of the `name` and `i` clutter in the global environment. These might cause some funny bugs later in the code if you're not careful. See also [Is R's apply family more than syntactic sugar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275896/is-rs-apply-family-more-than-syntactic-sugar)

Answer (score 5):

How about this :

```
for (i in c(1:numfiles)){  
    filenames[i] <- paste(".\\",filenames[i],sep="")  
    assign(gsub("[.]csv$","",filenames[i]),read.csv(filenames[i], header=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: apologies, i am relatively new to R, but I don't see how this creates dataframes named fxpair.yyyy.mm. I subbed in this code, ran it and then tried a ls() to make sure all of the csv files came in as dataframes named correctly but nothing other than "filenames" "fx.data.frames" and "i" exist. Thank you.