# Importing and reading multiple files R

Tags: r, plyr, read.table

I have numerous  tab delimited .txtfiles named as "*abcd001.txt, abcd002.txt"*.... stored in a directory.
I was able to import them using the following code, (whereby default directory is sames as data files directory). Its three column, all numeric type data

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".",pattern="abcd+.*txt")

#list of data in R
names <-substr(filenames,1,6)


for(i in names){
    filepath <- file.path(".",paste(i,".txt",sep=","))
    assign(i, read.table(filepath,
     colClasses=c("numeric"),
    sep = "\t"))
}
```

The code itself hasnt returned any error. My doubt is *How can I access data which is being loaded? How to access say the data of  the file abcd011.txt which should be three column data*

The commands:names[3] just returns the file number 000002 But no data.

The code here is similar to one here: [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames/13090509#13090509).

Comment: Your troubles illustrate nicely why using `assign` to store a collection of data does not work smoothly. If you want to get the contents of the variable, just use `get`. Alternatively, just put the data in a list, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend to put the results of `read.table` either in a list, or in one bit data.frame. In addition, I would recommend using `apply` style loops here, either standard R (`lapply`) or `plyr`. I prefer using `plyr`, so my examples will be using that package. An example:

```
## Read into a list of files:
filenames <- list.files(path=".",pattern="abcd+.*txt")
list_of_data = llply(filenames, read.table, 
                                        colClasses = c("numeric"), sep = "\t")
```

Accessing the data can now be done using:

```
list_of_data[[1]]
list_of_data[["abcd1.txt"]]
```

Or you could read the contents of the files into one big `data.frame`:

```
big_data = ldply(filenames, read.table, 
                             colClasses = c("numeric"), sep = "\t"))
```

Accessing the contents of a file can now be done using:

```
big_data[big_data$variable == "abcd1.txt",]
```

Comment: Thanks! The command `llply` worked. But with `ldply` and using `big_data[big_data$variable == "abcd1.txt"]` it returned `data frame with 0 coulmns and 203400 rows`. Why?

Comment: That is hard to say without example output. I guess that `"abcd1.txt"` is a non existent entry in the `variable` column.