# How to fill part of URL in loop

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

How can I fill part of URL with a for loop, I tried one URL it worked, eg:

```
data <- read.table("http://somelink.php?station=2&start=2012-01-01&etc", header=T,sep="|")
```

But when I changed the code into a loop, it failed:

```
station <- c(1:10)
Year <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y")

for (i in station){
data <- read.table("http://somelink.php?station=i&start=Year-01-01&etc", header=T,sep="|")
}
```

Comment: Ive never seen php coded like that before...

Comment: @craig1231, oh, the code is written in language R

Comment: So what help with PHP you need here? Is it tagged PHP only because there is `.php` in your url?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, Sorry about the confusion, I've edited the post

Comment: @Rosa no problem, I've edited your question to avoid further confusion. Ther is no such thing as `PHP URL`, it is standard format of URL used not only by PHP.

Comment: Thanks,dev-null-dweller. @mnel, I'll check that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your iterator `i` is inside the quotation marks and hence not being evaluated as intended.  use `paste0(.)`

---

Also, you may want your variable `data` to be list-like.  And perhaps not called `data`.

```
myData <- list(length = length(station))
for (i in station){
  urli <- paste0("http://somelink.php?station=", i, "&start=Year-01-01&etc")
  myData[[i]] <- read.table(urli, header=T,sep="|")
}
```

---

### Edit  (mnel)

or more idiomatically

```
urls <-paste0("http://somelink.php?station=",station, "&start=", Year, "01-01&etc")
myData <- lapply(urls, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = '|')
```

Comment: THANK YOU！The station gets running, but I didn't realize that couple of the stations have no data would result in an error, is there a way that can fix the error "no lines available in input"??

Comment: @rosa can you `dput(urls)` and post it, perhaps in another question?

Comment: @mnel,@Ricardo Saporta,I'm not sure if I understand the dput(urls) part, but I rewrited and posted another question, thanks

Comment: @Rosa if you `dput()` an R object, you'll get a string that someone else can paste into their R console to create that object. So if you paste the result of `dput(urls)` into your Stack Overflow question, it makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm partial to the `sprintf` function because it's easy to see what the final string will look like:

```
station_data <- list()
for (i in station) {
  station_data[[i]] <- read.table(sprintf("http://somelink.php?station=%s&start=Year-01-01&etc", i), 
    header=TRUE, sep="|")
}
```