# Read multiple csv files in a loop in R

Tags: r

I have csv tables named 001.csv, 002.csv to 200.csv. how can I select a given number of csv to read in a loop in R?? For example I have to read files from 095.csv to 105.csv.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your .csv files are in your working directory, you could do something like this:

```
listOfDataframes <- lapply(paste0(100:115, ".csv"), read.csv)
```

Or, in your slightly messier case where numbers < 100 begin with zero:

```
listOfDataframes <- lapply(c(paste0(0, 95:99, ".csv"),
                             paste0(100:115, ".csv")), read.csv)
```

Then you'll have a list of all those data.frames. You could then assign those data.frames to named objects with `mapply()`:

```
mapply(assign, paste0("df", 95:115),
       listOfDataframes, MoreArgs = list(envir= .GlobalEnv))
```