# Read data as a list in R

Tags: r

I can read data as a list of baskets rather than a data frame from an url like this:

```
url <- "http://www.salemmarafi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/groceries.csv"
baskets <- strsplit(readLines(url), ",", fixed=TRUE)
> head(baskets,2)
[[1]]
[1] "citrus fruit"        "semi-finished bread" "margarine"           "ready soups"        

[[2]]
[1] "tropical fruit" "yogurt"         "coffee"
```

But when I try to accomplish the same by loading data from a file the result is:

```
baskets2 <- strsplit(readLines("groceries.csv"), ",", fixed=TRUE)
> head(baskets2,2)
[[1]]
[1] "citrus fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"

[[2]]
[1] "tropical fruit;yogurt;coffee;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"
```

And with ";" it's:

```
> baskets2 <- strsplit(readLines("groceries.csv"), ";", fixed=TRUE)
> head(baskets2,2)
[[1]]
 [1] "citrus fruit"        "semi-finished bread" "margarine"           "ready soups"        
 [5] ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                   
 [9] ""                    ""                    ""                    ""                   
etc
```

How could I get the data to load similarly from a file on my computer (ie C:/mypath/groceries.csv) as it is loading from an url ie without the empty items ";;;;"?

*EDIT: This is only one csv and I'm trying to avoid loading it into a data frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

Comment: Try `read.csv()`. Then turn it into a list using `as.list()`. No calls to `strsplit()` are needed.

Comment: @Chani I don't think it is a duplicate of that question, though it might be of others

Comment: The solution provided by @Buckminster gives list with empty strings. An alternative is first use `readLines` and then `lapply(lines,  function(x){ unlist(strsplit(x, ",")) })`

Comment: As @jbkunst also provided an incorrect hint, here is a solution: `groc <- read.csv('groceries.csv', header = F)` `apply(groc, 1, function(x) unique(x)[unique(x)!=''])`. This can be optimized if you need to do this for bigger files but works pretty quick for your example.