# Remove non numeric values from vector in r

Tags: r, vector

Is there a simple way to remove all non numeric values from a vector in r?
Suppose we have:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, T, 'x', 'abc', '6', 7, F, F, 10)
```

I would like to receive:

```
c(1, 2, 7, 10)
```

Comment: Once you create `vec`, there are no numbers in it, all are strings.

Comment: Why not `6`? If you want that, too, then `as.numeric(grep("^-?[0-9.]+$", c(1, 2, T, 'x', 'abc', '6', 7, F, F, 10), value=TRUE))`.

Comment: If `6` is truly not wanted, then ... you cannot, period. By using `c(...)`, all elements within the vector are converted to the highest common class, which in this case is `character`, so there is no way to differentiate between what was originally `"6"` and what was originally `6`. If you truly want that, use a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `Filter` over `vec <- list(1, 2, T, 'x', 'abc', '6', 7, F, F, 10)`, i.e.,

```
> unlist(Filter(is.numeric,vec))
[1]  1  2  7 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to look for elements that only contain the digits 0-9 along with periods and return them. The `^` matches the start of a character and `$` matches the end so it will filter out any element which has both letters and numbers.

```r
as.numeric(grep('^-?[0-9.]+$', vec, val = T))
```

Comment: We think alike :-). BTW, you don't need to escape the `.` it doesn't mean "any character" inside the bracket-group.

Comment: Huh, nice. I guess that makes sense - a wildcard inside the brackets would kinda defeat their purpose.

Comment: It's one reason why some R programmers prefer `[.]` over `\\.` ... many (including me) find the double-backslash thing harder to read than the bracket notation. And R's preference towards double-backslashes (vice singles) means it is no better/worse in code-golf.

Answer (score 2):

`c` is a function that returns a vector where "all arguments are coerced to a common type...The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression."

Thus, you need a container where you can have mixed data types to test which ones are numeric.  A `list` gives you this.  This approach leaves out the `'6'`:

`vec_list <- list(1, 2, T, 'x', 'abc', '6', 7, F, F, 10)`
`unlist(vec_list[sapply(vec_list, function(x) if(class(x)=='numeric') {T} else {F})])`

[1]  1  2  7 10

Comment: It's hard to read all the code wrapped around in one line like this. Why not save the list to a variable first, so you don't have to declare it twice like this? Also, switching to a list works if the OP is able to create their data from the start, but what about cases where this is data they're reading in from some other source?

Comment: Good suggestion for readability @camille, so I did that.  For your other question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823093/read-data-as-a-list-in-r for possible help

Answer (score 0):

Techically the term vector includes lists that do not have attributes other than names, so here is a vector built with `list` rather than with `c`.

```
vec <- list(1, 2, T, 'x', 'abc', '6', 7, F, F, 10)
```

So that can be tested for "numericy"

```
vec[sapply(vec, is.numeric)]
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 7

[[4]]
[1] 10
```