# How to read CSV files in a loop?

Tags: r, file, csv, dataframe

I am new to R and now I have an issue while I try to read CSV files in a loop. My CSV files are named as

```
result_file_1.csv , result_file_2.csv,....result_file_10.csv
```

So I planned to read a CSV by the below code:

```
for(i in 1:10){
t1=read.csv("result_file_i.csv")
// rest of my code
}
```

I also tried:

```
for(i in 1:10){
    t1=read.csv("result_file_"+i+".csv")
    // rest of my code
    }
```

both did not work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: use `paste0()` to get the filename; `read.csv(paste0("result_file_", i , ".csv"))`

Comment: @joel.wilson Works like a charm.Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad could help! however this was a poor question reflecting you didn't put much efforts to search online Sir. please do take it in a positive sense. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As suggested above I used  `paste0("result_file",i,".csv")` and it worked fine.