# How do I read multiple txt file and save them as respective object names?

Tags: r

I have hundreds of `.txt` files. I want to automate a process to read them all and save them with their respective file name. For example, I want to save them in this order without typing the name of individual files.

```
mytext1.txt <-read.table("./mytext1.txt", sep = "\t")
mytext2.txt <-read.table("./mytext2.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Here is the code I have tried which of course doesn't save the dataframe in a separate object name.

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")   
datalist = lapply(filelist, FUN=read.table, header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Why not name the entries of `datalist` by `filelist`? `names(datalist) <- filelist`.

Comment: This question has been asked several times already, but the dupe target is not good, because the OP of the duped question has stated that he has only 8 files with *different file structures*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a line:

```
datafr = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

See this post for reference: [How do you read in multiple .txt files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r)

Comment: Thanks, but I want them in a separate dataframe with their respective file names.

Comment: My mistake. Instead, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames. 
It looks like the assign function is what you're looking for.

Comment: @stevebroll The OP in the linked question is stating that he has just 8 files of *different file structure*. If there is a large number of files having the same structure it's better to store them in a list or `rbindlist()` them, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but it should do what you want:

```
read.and.write.table <- function(files){
    for(fn in files){
        input <- read.table(file = fn, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
        assign(x = fn, value = input, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}

filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")  
read.and.write.table(filelist)
```

Will create separate global variables named after your .txt files. Of course you could include some string manipulation to pretty up the names.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`: *The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign function.
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)*