# Multiple import of tsv files works only for the first file

Tags: r, import

I have N .tsv files saved in a file named "data" into my rstudio working directory and I want to find a way to import them as separated data frames at once. Below is an example when I try to do it one by one but there are too many of them and I want something faster. Also every time their total number may be different.

```
#read files into R
f1<-read.table(file = 'a_CompositeSources/In1B1A_WDNdb_DrugTargetInteractions_CompositeDBs_Adhesion.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
f2<-read.table(file = 'a_CompositeSources/In1B2A_WDNdb_DrugTargetInteractions_CompositeDBs_Cy.tsv',sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

I have N .tsv files saved in a file named "data" into my rstudio working directory and I want to find a way to import them as separated data frames at once. Below is an example when I try to do it one by one but there are too many of them and I want something faster. Also every time their total number may be different.

```
#read files into R
f1<-read.table(file = 'a_CompositeSources/In1B1A_WDNdb_DrugTargetInteractions_CompositeDBs_Adhesion.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
f2<-read.table(file = 'a_CompositeSources/In1B2A_WDNdb_DrugTargetInteractions_CompositeDBs_Cytochrome.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames) I have used :

```
    library(readr)
    library(dplyr)


    ##Read files named xyz1111.csv, xyz2222.csv, etc.
    filenames <- list.files(path="C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data",
                            pattern="*.tsv")

    ##Create list of data frame names without the ".csv" part 
    names <-gsub(".tsv", "", filenames)

    ###Load all files
    for(i in names){
      filepath <- file.path("C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data",paste(i,".tsv",sep=""))
      assign(i, read.delim(filepath,
                           colClasses=c("factor","character",rep("numeric",2)),
                           sep = "\t"))
    }
```

but only the 1st file is read.

Comment: Consider using **one** list of similarly structured data frames and avoid flooding your global environment with *many* objects to tediously track and recall. So just use *tbl*: `tbl[[1]]`, `tbl[[2]]`, `tbl[[3]]` or `tbl$file1.csv`, `tbl2$file2.csv`, `tbl$file3.csv`

Comment: It might be difficult to answer this without knowing something about the files. I can do it with a contrived triple-saved `mtcars.tsv` and your `sapply(...) %>% bind_rows()` works fine. (That is the preferred method, btw; using a `for` loop with `assign` usually makes things much harder than they need to be.)

Comment: @Parfait -- I typed the same comment, then realized (before posting) that the first 5 lines of that code block include almost exactly that.

Comment: For above comment, `.csv` should be `.tsv`!

Comment: firmo23, you might consider not using common functions as variable names: `names` and (since you're using `dplyr`) `tbl` are common-enough. While R is usually smart-enough to know which you want, it is not hard to contrive situations where it is not as clear ... and troubleshooting problems due to that can be unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: They all have 4 columns the first is a factor the second is character and the other 2 numeric. The names are those that I have provided in the Q.

Comment: firmo23, you use a sub-directory in your first (successfully-read?) examples: `'a_CompositeSources/In1B1A...tsv'`. Then you use `"C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data"`, notably *without* `recursive=TRUE`. How certain are you that all files you expect are included in `files` and/or `filenames`?

Comment: filenames and names are correctly created. I can see that.

Comment: Based on your question, then, the fact that you can successfully read `f1` and `f2` has nothing to do with the success or failure of reading files listed in `filenames`, since they are different files. Am I mistaken? Can you successfully do `readr::read_tsv(filenames[1])` and `readr::read_tsv(filenames[2])` and `readr::read_tsv(filenames[length(filenames)])`?

Comment: You mention *"import them as separated data frames"* but then your code includes `bind_rows()`, which will combine them. Does this mean that your first few lines of code worked, but you didn't realize you were combining all frames into a single frame? (This might make you think that only one file was read.) If you do just `tbl <- sapply(files, read_tsv, simplify=FALSE)`, does `length(tbl)` indicate you read something in for all files?

Comment: sorry ignore the bind_rows() chunk it was there by mistake. I want separated dataframes

Comment: You also removed the code that I (and Parfait) suggest and that code works for me with multiple files (`sapply(filenames, readr::read_tsv, simplify = FALSE)`). So perhaps there is some form of disconnect with your `filenames`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your problem

```
# empty list
data = list()

###Load all files 
for(i in names){ 
filepath <- file.path("C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data",paste(i,".tsv",sep="")) 
data[i] = read.delim(filepath, colClasses=c("factor","character",rep("numeric",2)), sep = "\t")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this with `map()`:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data",
                    pattern="*.tsv") %>% 
 as_tibble() %>% 
 mutate(
    data = map(value, ~ read.delim(glue::glue("C:/Users/user/Documents/kate/data/{.x}"), colClasses=c("factor","character",rep("numeric",2)), sep = "\t"))
  )
```