# Get most current file in R - Rstudio

Tags: r, directory

I use R. Currently, I need to enter a folder of the computer, and within that folder there are other folders, each of which has numerous excel files, I need to get the most current of each folder.

folder structure:

```
C: \ book \

C: \ book \ x
C: \ book \ x \ x.xlsx
C: \ book \ x \ xx.xlsx
C: \ book \ x \ xxx.xlsx

C: \ book \ y
...
C: \ book \ z
...
```

Is there any way to do this optimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly a dupe of one of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 or [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319839/3358272). For the latter, I counter with a suggestion to store the frames in a `list`-of-frames and not individual files, but ... that is contextual and might not be ideal for your particular use.

Regardless, here's an adaptation that incorporates "most recent file":

```r
LF <- list.files(path = "path/to", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
recent_LF <- c(by(LF, dirname(LF), function(filenames) {
  filenames[ which.max(file.info(filenames)[,"mtime"]) ]
}))
```

**Edit**:
sometimes I consider that `list.files` should default to:

```r
list.files <- function(path, ..., recursive = FALSE, full.names = recursive, ...) {
  # ...
}
```

I see no value in `recursive=TRUE, full.names=FALSE`, which is what happened with the first version of this answer.

Comment: The listing worked, however, a function of the error:
`Error in file.info(filenames) : invalid filename argument
Called from: file.info(filenames)`

Comment: Check the contents of `LF`. Are any of them `NA`? Did you use something other than this `list.files(.)` call to create it?

Comment: The entire list has some file. I use the list.files()

Comment: OK, yes, add `full.names=TRUE`.

Comment: Error in file.info(filenames) : invalid filename argument

Comment: to be clear, the `full.names` goes with `list.files`, not with `file.info`.

Comment: I managed to solve it that way: xxx[i] <- yyy[which.max(file.mtime(yyy))]

Comment: I only got it based on your answer, thanks!