# How to bind multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have imported many csv files into R using the code provided here: [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

Now I have plenty of dataframes that I try to bind together into one. I've tried to use bind_rows to do that in a following way:

```
all<- bind_rows(names, .id = "id")
```

where "names" contains files/dataframes names.

I get the following error: "Argument 1 must have names."

How can I bind all the dfs?

Comment: You should have used https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/680068 , so that your dataframes are in a list, then `all <- bind_rows(myListOfDataFrames)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `names` store the object names of objects created in the global environment, then we need the value of those.  We can get those with `mget` in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(names), .id = 'id')
```