# R function for grouping imported csv files

Tags: r

I’ve imported a bunch of csv files and now I need to group them all into categories (high, medium and low)
Does anyone know an r function for this?

I tried creating lists but then I realised I had just made character lists of the file names themselves rather than the actual files

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.