# How to read multiple csv files into a single data frame in R?

Tags: r

How to read multiple csv files into a single data frame in R?

Similar questions have been asked here:

- [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames/73447396?noredirect=1#comment132728786_73447396) most answers use the `assign()` function to assign to many data frames.
- [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) most answers add data frames to a list of data frames using `append(l, df)` or `l[[i]]=df`.

## Reproducible example

Write sample csv files to a temporary directory.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(purrrlyr)
library(readr)
data_dir <- file.path(tempdir(), "iris")
dir.create(data_dir)
iris %>%
    # To keep the Species column in the output
    # Create a new column that will be used as the grouping variable
    mutate(species_group = Species) %>%
    group_by(species_group) %>%
    nest() %>%
    # Apply the write.csv() function to each row of the nested data frame
    by_row(~write.csv(.$data,
                      file = file.path(data_dir, paste0(.$species_group, ".csv")),
                      row.names = FALSE))
```

In this example, there are 3 `.csv` files in the `data_dir`. The question is how to read them all into a single data frame.

Answer (score 3):

To read many csv files into one data frame:

1. Lists files with their full path.
2. Apply the `read_csv` function to each element of the vector of file paths and return a data frame created by row-binding.

```
iris_csv <- list.files(data_dir, full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(read_csv)
```