Import multiple txt files into R and simplify the code
I need to import 8 txt files into R. Is there a way to grab them all together? I want to import them into seperate files.
The file names are similar to each other, is there a way to avoid repetitiveness?
Original:
pbp_2020_total <- read.delim("2020_pbp_b10_amb_trans.txt")
pbp_2020_vbid <- read.delim("2020_pbp_b10_b19b_amb_trans_vbid_uf.txt")
pbp_2021_total <- read.delim("2021_pbp_b10_amb_trans.txt")
pbp_2021_vbid <- read.delim("2021_pbp_b10_b19b_amb_trans_vbid_uf.txt")
pbp_2022_total <- read.delim("2022_pbp_b10_amb_trans.txt")
pbp_2022_vbid <- read.delim("2022_pbp_b10_b19b_amb_trans_vbid_uf.txt")
pbp_2023_total <- read.delim("2023_pbp_b10_amb_trans.txt")
pbp_2023_vbid <- read.delim("2023_pbp_b10_b19b_amb_trans_vbid_uf.txt")


Also tried the code below but it didn't work.
"/Users/yun/Documents/U/Spring 2024/" is where all the files are saved.
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
line 2 did not have 65 elements
folder <- "/Users/yun/Documents/U/Spring 2024/" 

txt_files <- list.files(path=folder, pattern=".txt")

df= c(rep(data.frame(), length(txt_files)))

for(i in 1:length(txt_files)) {df[[i]]<- as.list(read.table(file.path(folder, txt_files[i])))}


Have you read this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames

I think the most typical workflow would be to make a list of the files you want (could be formulaic, like files_vbid <- paste0(2020:2023, "_pbp_b10_b19b_amb_trans_vbid_uf.txt"), and then use lapply or purrr::map to run read.delim with each of those files as input. It is generally best practice to read related files into a list instead of as separate, free-floating objects, so as to simplify any future processing and organizing steps.

Have you tried as above read.delim instead of read.table in the for loop?
